# LessCss on Java, what version is being used?

Tags: less

I just sent this to Alexis Sellier `<self@cloudhead.net>` but it bounced back, prompting me to seek answers here:

---

```
Hi Alexis,

First and foremost, thanks for a great Java support for the lesscss library!

I am and have been for a while on version 1.7.0.1.1.

I was attempting to use the extend feature which worked when used as:

.button-a {
        &:extend(.button-base);
        .rounded-corners-top(7px);
}
```

**but not when used as**

```
.button-a:extend(.button-base) {   
        .rounded-corners-top(7px);    
}

further more, the first case does not work if button-base well looks like this: 

.button-base {
    ...

    &:hover {
            background-color: white;
            color: #ff3c1f;
    }
}
```

**The hover stuff never gets active from extended contexts. Does this work in the JS version?**

```
I tried to peek into the java package and it seems you have merged
what I believe to be the JS library with some other Rhino JS code,
making it hard to upgdrade to the latest JS version.

It is not clear from the Java library what version is being used either.

I have myself written another js library and successfully used Rhino,
EnvJS and my JS library, and I choose to approach it a bit
differently, namely that the JS can be supplied separately, as an
argument to my java class which takes care of merging it all.


Is that something you think is possible? If not, how up to date with
the JS code is the current Java version?


What limitations do you see in going the approach I've mentioned above.
```

Comment: 1. >`.button-a:extend(.button-base)`works fine in standard Less version so it's probably some Rhino branch bug (probably it's should be fixed by now since current Less version is 2.4.0). 2. "The hover stuff never gets active from extended contexts" - Read about the difference between `extend` and [extend all`](http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature-extend-all-) 3. See below.

Comment: For the Rhino installation and usage - sorry, no idea. But to answer about "just JS library" approach: there's no *pure* "JS library" version as such - there's `node`, `browser` and `rhino` versions and each has a couple of its environment depended things that simply do not present and/or won't work in others.

Comment: Yes, and welcome to the SO. A few hints: a. it's not a good idea to put multiple unrelated problems into one Q here. b. it's not either a good idea to format it this way (pasting the whole content of the email as a code snippet or so).

Comment: @seven-phases-max thanks for you answer. I am thinking about the browser version which should be possible to mimic in a java version. The problem is that the way it is built it is not easy to replace used version. Any idea of who is managing the java version? it seems a bit outdated now. It's been a year since it was last updated.

Comment: Well, the main trick there is that the browser version is made to read page links, compile those of `less` and inject the CSS results back to the page (+ a couple of more minor client-side version actions). I don't think this is what you expect to be performed in your Rhino version.

Comment: >Any idea of who is managing the java version? - I think it would be fine to ask at the corresponding issue trackers [here](https://github.com/SomMeri/less-rhino.js/issues) or finally [here](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues) (this is not quite an issue itself of course but since an up-to-date "How to use in Rhino" documentation is probably [missing](http://lesscss.org/#command-line-with-rhino) (?) (and that's already an issue) - that would actually make sense).

Comment: @seven-phases-max Yes, but the reading of links from a the page should not yield any errors since there won't be any. Furthermore, through the use of Rhino the less files should be explitlity set before attempting to render them, so that they are fetched from cache and not through an xmlhttprequest

Comment: Well, it's your decision. It's just about using something in a way it's not supposed to be used (this is especially important since the browser version is reduced in features, the least recommended to use and eventually it will get less and less support and attention).